# Local authentication on postgres failing

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, pg-dump

I'm trying to configure a script that is run regularly by cron. I update the Postgres config to trust local connections but I'm getting a peer authentication error.

#### error

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo /data/postgresql-backup.sh
pg_dump: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "rails_admin"
```

#### /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf

```
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

#### /data/postgresql-backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

BACKUP_DIR="/data/psql-db-backup/"
FILE_NAME=$BACKUP_DIR`date +%d-%m-%Y-%I-%M-%S-%p`.sql
pg_dump -U rails_admin rails_production_db > $FILE_NAME
```

Comment: " I update the Postgres config to trust local connections".  No, you updated it to trust 'localhost' connections, which is not the same as local connections.  You could specify `-h 127.0.0.1` to your psql command, or you could change your pg_hba.conf again  to reflect what you really want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only run that script as operating system user `rails_admin`, because only that user would be allowed to connect with `peer` authentication.

You can either relax `peer` to `trust` (if you trust all operating system users on the database server machine), or you can add a [user name map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-username-maps.html) to `pg_ident.conf` that allows the operating system user to connect as database user `rails_admin`.